# ASP.NET Core app starts on VS Code but not VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am building an app with .Net Core 2.2. When I run it using Visual Studio Code it works perfectly fine. I cannot get it to work using "full" Visual Studio 2017.

After starting it, i get error System.IO.FileNotFoundException, cannot load System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

This is beginning of my*.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
     <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
     <GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>
     <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
     <GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />    
    <PackageReference Include="vue" Version="2.5.17" />  
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.3" />     
  </ItemGroup>
```

Im sure I have proper .NET SDK and runtime installed, because my app works on other IDE. What to do to start it in VS2017?

Comment: 1) What the exact version number of your VS2017? 15.9 or any other? 2) What's the SDK version? VS2017 requires certain versions, if you check .NET Core SDK download page (VSCode does not have this limitation).

Comment: VS2017 is 15.9.11.  I have .net 2.2.203 installed

Comment: Then clearly you hit this https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/108

Comment: I installed the newest from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download and nothing changed

Comment: If you even read the title of that link you notice that **.NET Core SDK 2.2.2nn and 2.1.6nn do not work with Visual Studio 2017**.

Comment: Try to upgrade your VS to 2019.